# safari svg with double-width ellipse

Tags: svg, safari, ellipse

I'm trying to create a simple SVG with ellipse elements, but in Safari (and only Safari), it's drawing all *non-circular* ellipses with doubled stroke width. If the ellipse is perfectly circular (`rx == ry`) then it draws it normally.

Has anyone seen this behavior before, or have any idea how to work around it? I'm seeing the behavior on macOS 10.12.1, Safari 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7). It also only appears on my retina display (2014 MBP) and not on an external non-retina display.

Here's the html file I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<style>
  circle {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: none;
  }
  ellipse {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: none;
  }
</style>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/> <!--Draws with normal stroke-->
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40"/> <!--Draws with normal stroke-->
  <ellipse cx="70" cy="70" rx="40" ry="20"/> <!--Draws with doubled stroke-->
  <ellipse cx="80" cy="80" rx="20" ry="20"/> <!--Draws with normal stroke-->
</svg>

</body>
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: svg with doubled ellipse stroke]

Comment: If you've found a webkit bug, [report it](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: It appears correctly to me in Safari v10 https://jsfiddle.net/x2m2zyzv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with an underlying framework. It will be rectified in the next OS update. 
 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=164505#c3